# Kotlin Multiplatform HTML linking

Tags: javascript, html, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm just learning about Kotlin Multiplatform in Android Studio. Before learning about this I linked HTML files and JS files to my Android project and it worked. In MainActivity I had:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
}
```

So my question is, in the Kotlin Multiplatform module how do I do something similar in the shared commonMain folder? Is this possible? I'm very new to this so any advice you can give I greatly appreciate. Thanks everyone!

I tried to look up how to write up this code. I found basic documentation on how to write in shared but not how to link HTML and JS files.